# Is Luke 11:8 about honor or persistence?

Tags: luke, hapax-legomenon

In Luke 11:5-8, Jesus tells the parable about a man woken from sleep by his friend asking for bread in the middle of the night. In verse 8 we read (bolding mine):

> λέγω ὑμῖν, εἰ καὶ⸌ οὐ δώσει αὐτῷ ἀναστὰς διὰ τὸ εἶναι ⸂φίλον αὐτοῦ⸃, **διά γε τὴν ἀναίδειαν αὐτοῦ** ἐγερθεὶς δώσει αὐτῷ ὅσων χρῄζει. <sub>[(NA28)](http://www.academic-bible.com/en/online-bibles/novum-testamentum-graece-na-28/read-the-bible-text/bibelstelle/luke%2011%3A8/bibel/text/lesen/ch/e8d10f2e6e8de02bc32b9e5ad27866c1/)</sub>
>
> I tell you, even though the man inside will not get up and give him anything because he is his friend, yet **because of the first man’s sheer persistence** he will get up and give him whatever he needs. <sub>([NET](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Luke+11:8))</sub>

The NET here goes to pains to point out that αὐτοῦ refers to the asker, and ἀναίδεια is taken to mean 'persistence.' (The [note there](https://net.bible.org/#!bible/Luke+11:8) defends this decision.) However, [other translations](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Luke%2011:8) use 'impudence', and in many it seems unclear grammatically whether it refers to the householder or his petitioner. The translation I found that goes farthest in the opposite direction from the NET is from the NICNT commentary:<sup>1</sup>

> I tell you, even if he will not get up and give him anything because he is his friend, **in order to avoid dishonor** he will get up and give him whatever he needs.

A footnote there states, regarding the translation of ἀναίδεια:

> “Persistence” is not a viable option. ἀναίδεια is an abstract noun formed from the negation of αἱδώς (via αἱδός, “shame, self-respect, what causes shame or scandal”).

What is the intended meaning of ἀναίδεια here, and is it attributed to the slumbering man or his nocturnal supplicant?

---

<sub>1. Joel B. Green, The Gospel of Luke (NICNT; Accordance electronic ed. Grand Rapids: Eerdmans, 1997), 445.</sub>

Comment: You have the best questions, Susan. :)

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling that regardless of how one translates the parable, there is truth in each translation. Is, perhaps, one translation closer to the truth which Luke and Jesus intended to communicate? Probably. To me, the important thing is that a translation (and later, an interpretation) fits the context (and all that that entails!).

***The Importance of Hospitality***

In ANE culture, opening one's home to friends and strangers was a kind of sacred trust and responsibility. Almost like a "city of refuge," one's home was where "outsiders" could feel welcomed, accepted, loved, and even protected (see Genesis 19:1-8, esp. v.8). Today we have an expression: "Make yourself at home," which being translated means "Be as comfortable in my home as you are in yours. *Mi casa es su casa*."

Another good example of hospitality, which I'll throw in for free, is found in Genesis 18:1-8, where we see that strangers are entitled to foot washing, some refreshment (viz., grub!), and maybe even a place to sleep for the night. A qualification for elders in the NT church, by the way, is that they be lovers of strangers (filovxenoß, 1 Timothy 3:2 KJV); that is, that they be given to hospitality, or are lovers of hospitality, or use hospitality on a regular basis. See also Romans 12:13, where diwvkw + filoxea translate into pursuing hospitality. Instead of keeping strangers at a distance, good Christians are to seek them out, approach them (not stalk them!), and attend to their needs, three of the most important of which are to feel welcomed, accepted, and loved. 
Compare, also, Luke 7:36-47 and John 13:1-5, for insight into Simon's *faux pas* and the disciples' self-centeredness.

***Avoiding Dishonor or Sheer Persistence: Either/or, or Both/And?***

The concept of **"avoiding dishonor"** is quite apt, I believe, particularly if the dishonor would be on the head of the supplicant who is obligated to be a good host. The concept of persistence, too, goes along quite nicely with a felt obligation, since wanting to be a good host to one's guests might sometimes involve importuning a benefactor for, say, bread(!), in order to save face. If the benefactor is a good friend, well then s/he wouldn't want his/her friend to lose face. In Jesus' parable, however, given the ungodly hour of the night, a little persistence from the suppliant couldn't hurt, even though it might be resisted at first, despite the friendship. (Though Jesus' parable does not mention the benefactor's guilt, guilt is certainly implied, but it's not the primary reason for the benefactor's leaving his nice warm bed, where he and his children are comfortably ensconced.)

***The Real Application***

In relation to our supplicating God, which is really at the heart of Jesus' teaching here, God wants us to be persistent in our supplications, not because He is reluctant to give us what we ask for, but because if we truly desire to have "his will be done" (Luke 11:2b), we need to go through a process, if you will, of refining our motives so that they are in line with God's will. In other words, we need to think biblically about what it is we are asking for.

This refining process takes time and persistence and perhaps even a delayed answer from God, which to us may seem to be completely unnecessary and unwarranted. Is this perhaps why the Psalms encourages us to be patient and to "wait on the LORD"? I think so.

***In Conclusion***

James, Jesus' stepbrother, hits us where we live when he asks,

> What is the source of quarrels and conflicts among you? Is not the source your pleasures that wage war in your members? You lust and do not have; so you commit murder. You are envious and cannot * obtain; so you fight and quarrel. You do not have because you do not ask. You ask and do not receive, because you ask with wrong motives, so that you may spend it on your pleasures. You adulteresses, do you not know that friendship with the world is hostility toward God? (James 4:1-4 NASB).

In other words, is our motive for asking simply to satisfy a selfish desire (e.g., "O Lord, won't ya buy me a Mercedes Benz," as Janis Joplin intoned), or do we really desire God's will to be done in our given situation? I'll leave it at that.

Answer (score 1):

### Who is ἀναίδεια attributed to?

Luke 11:8 λέγω ὑμῖν, εἰ καὶ οὐ δώσει αὐτῷ ἀναστὰς διὰ τὸ εἶναι φίλον **αὐτοῦ**, διά γε τὴν ἀναίδειαν **αὐτοῦ** ἐγερθεὶς δώσει αὐτῷ ὅσων χρῄζει.

Grammatically it is possible to read the second "αὐτοῦ" (his) as referring to either the slumbering man or his nocturnal supplicant. Neither reading will materially change the teaching of the text which is brought out in vv.9-10. That being said, we would likely find the two uses of "αὐτοῦ" (his) to refer to the same person, namely the nocturnal supplicant, as many commentators do:

> 11:8 Because of the man’s boldness. This refers to the petitioner’s
>   refusal to give up until his neighbour met his need.<sup>1</sup>

### The translation of ἀναίδεια

The basic meaning behind ἀναίδεια seems to be a lack of shame<sup>2</sup>. If we take both uses of "αὐτοῦ" (his) as referring to the petitioner, then how is the nocturnal supplicant being insensitive to what is proper (acting with a lack of shame)? In context his shamelessness seems to be more than just the audacity of coming to his friend at night, as v.7 makes clear, since the friend does not consider this a good enough reason to get out of bed.

> Luke 11:7 "and he will answer from within and say,`Do not trouble me;
>   the door is now shut, and my children are with me in bed; I cannot
>   rise and give to you '?

Clearly, there is more than just coming at night that is being refered to here. In 18:1–8 the emphasis is on persistence, hence the translation.

If we take the second "αὐτοῦ" (his) as referring to the friend who is asleep, then as the NICNT commentary suggests "αὐτοῦ" would refer to his unwillingness to be shamed, which according to v.7 is not a concern for the friend.

### Concluding thoughts

Whilst the second "αὐτοῦ" (his) could be attributed to either man, to me it seems most probable to read it as referring to the nocturnal supplicant, as that is the more natural reading, grammatically and contextually.

---

notes

<sup>1</sup> Stein, R. H. (1992). Luke (Vol. 24, p. 327). Nashville: Broadman & Holman Publishers.

<sup>2</sup> 66.12 ἀναίδεια, ας f: a lack of sensitivity to what is proper—‘insolence, audacity, impudence, shamelessness.’ διά γε τὴν ἀναίδειαν αὐτοῦ ἐγερθεὶς δώσει αὐτῷ ὅσων χρῄζει ‘but he will get up and give what he needs because of his insolence (in keeping on asking)’ or ‘… because he lacks a sense of what is proper’ Lk 11:8.Louw, [J. P., & Nida, E. A. (1996). Greek-English lexicon of the New Testament: based on semantic domains (electronic ed. of the 2nd edition., Vol. 1, p. 627). New York: United Bible Societies.]

Comment: @susan, One  hermeneutical tool used resolve questions like this one is **scenario analysis** which entails reconstituting the cultural situation represented in the narrative which becomes a sort of puzzle into which word meanings and grammatical idioms fit or do not fit. This is not simply reference to “context” as you find in every book on hermeneutics, it is more complex than that. Check the introductory chapters in:  
[**Scenarios, Discourse, and Translation**, Richard A. Hoyle, 2008 SIL International](http://www-01.sil.org/silepubs/Pubs/50670/50670_Hoyle_ScenariosDiscourseTranslation.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, @C.StirlingBartholomew, I’ll take a look. FYI, in order to ping using `@user`, the person has to have been involved in the post, editing or comments (now I have, but I hadn’t when you wrote that so I didn’t get it). You could ping on a comment under my question, or feel free to drop by [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1505/the-library) if interested. But obviously I found this, so thanks for the resource!

Answer (score 1):

A look at the context suggests that since the apostles asked to be taught to pray and not how to pray that maybe the message that Jesus gives in the parable was that the "honor/Shame" of the man in the house represents GOd's Honor/shame in His willingness give good gifts to those who ask? If you being evil, how much more will your Father give...

Comment: Persistence is taught in Lk 18:1 and following.